# Least squares with equality constraint

Tags: linear-programming, least-squares, projection, quadratic-programming

Say I have the following Least Squares equation with constraints and constant parameters $a_i$:

$\min(\sum(x_{i}-a_{i})^2), \sum{x_{i}}=1,x_i>0$

Basically, I am looking for the best set of $x_i$'s to minimise this function while ensuring their sum equals 1. I am not trying to model any data, so it is not a traditional use-case.

Is there an analytical solution to this problem? Or do I have to look at quadratic programming or iterative approaches? If so, any pointers? I haven't been able to work anything out myself.

I do not need a perfect solution, so some reasonable algorithmic estimate is sufficient.

Comment: Isn’t this a typical Lagrange multiplier problem? // I do not see the connection to statistics, so I have voted to migrate to Math.SE.

Comment: You said you are not trying to model any data, so I agree with @Dave

Answer (score 2):

If your vector $x$ has $n$ components, then simply set all $x_i:=\frac{1}{n}$. Then $\bar{x}=\frac{1}{n}$, each $x_i$ is equal to this mean, your sum of squares is zero (so it is minimal, because anything else would be greater than zero), and your constraints are satisfied.

And I agree with [Dave](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590206/least-squares-with-equality-constraint/590209#comment1091864_590206) that this would be a better fit for Math.SE.

Comment: This answer is correct for the original problem I posed. I apologise, I did not frame it correctly and have since edited. The means I derive are estimated means from another source and act as constant parameter in solving this minimisation...

Comment: So, are your $a_i$ simply external observations (so we have a standard case of [tag:constrained-regression], we should have threads on that), or do they have anything to do with the mean of $x$ (which your use of "means" suggests)?

Comment: Okay, to provide context, I have $n$ possible outcomes of a sporting event. A bookkeeper is offering certain "odds" for each outcome, but these "odds" include some margin. $a_i$ represents the bookkeeper's "probability" of the $i$th outcome, but these don't sum to 1 since the margins inflate these numbers. I am trying to recover the true probability of each outcome by "getting as close to" the bookkeeper "probability" for each outcome  as possible but constraining the total probability to 1. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks. There is no general analytical solution for this kind of problem. It's a case of quadratic programming with linear equality and inequality constraints (the sum of the coefficients and them being nonnegative, respectively). [Here is how to do this in R.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/21565/1352) Your favorite piece of software should be able to do this as well. Maybe look at [OR.SE](https://or.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks for this, managed to solve the problem using AlgLib in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Without the requirement that $x_i \ge 0$, you can get a closed-form expression for the optimal solution:
$$x_i = a_i + \frac{1-\sum_j a_j}{n}$$

This formula arises geometrically from finding the smallest distance from $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ to the hyperplane $\sum_i x_i=1$ or algebraically from Lagrange multipliers.

As a check, note that
$$
\sum_i \left(a_i + \frac{1-\sum_j a_j}{n}\right) = \sum_i a_i + \left(1-\sum_j a_j\right) = 1,
$$
as required.
Furthermore, if $\sum_j a_j = 1$, the proposed formula yields $x_i=a_i$, with objective value zero.